# Use of Routing in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, url-routing

Why we are using routing in cakePHP and what would be the basic approaches for implementation...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing allows aliasing and routing(!) of URLs. It gives us a cleaner, more controlled interface and underpins the functioning of CakePHP.

The first step would be to read the appropriate chapter in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/view/542/Defining-Routes (1.2) or http://book.cakephp.org/view/948/Defining-Routes (1.3)

Then look at the routes.php file (`app/config/routes.php`) to understand how it goes together.

Finally, when you know what you want to do (we don't because you haven't told us), try it debug it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

### Why

Because it allows you to decouple your URLs from your controller actions. You can name your controllers and actions in a way that makes sense internally, and invoke them using URLs that do not need to bear any resemblance to your internal naming scheme.
`FooApiVersion1Controller::internal_beta_method()` can be invoked by the URL `/api/v1/method`, and you can swap out the controller or method at any time without needing to change the URL.

### How

Read the manual. http://book.cakephp.org/view/945/Routes-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/310/Configuration

```
<?php
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
?>
```